# Due to or Because of

Tags: meaning, grammar, word-usage, american-english, learning

As I know Because of is an adverb which describes the verb and Due to is an adjective that describes the noun.

Could you please notify the noun and verb that each of them modifying in the following sentences?

1. This in turn will stimulate further investment due to the multiplier
   effect
2. and it is because of these health hazards that stays on the
   International Space Station are restricted to six months.
3. Bamboo is a favored plant among architects and designers because of
   its incredible strength and durability.

Comment: In the first sentence of your question, you should not start with _As I know_ in English. If you want something like that, use _As I've been taught_. If you are a student, you should not start a question with what you think you know. You're probably wrong, after all -- that's why you're a student asking a question. In fact, both of them often modify phrases, clauses, and full sentences; that's why they can be exchanged so easily here..

Comment: Thanks sir for being so patient and answering. But are they interchangeable?

Comment: "Due to" was once used only accompanied by the verb *to be*: "His illness WAS due to..." and it could be replaced by "caused by": "The symptoms ARE caused by..." Where there was no be/is/are/was/were, we wretches who cared about such things would use "because of" (or "owing to"): "He became ill owing to...", "He died because of..." We would not have said, "He became ill due to smoking."